# Why taking combinations works but conventional approach does not in this case?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is 
Let two items be chosen from a lot containing 12 items of which 4 are defective. Find the probability that atleast one item is defective.

**Approach 1:**
$$
\frac{4}{12}\times\frac{8}{11}+\frac{4}{12}\times\frac{3}{11} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

First term represents the case in which one item is defective and second is not defective.
Here $\frac{4}{12}$ is probability choosing one item from $4$ defective items out of $12$ items.
As a result, now there are $11$ items are there to choose from. $\frac{8}{11}$ is probability of choosing one from $8$ non-defective item out of $11$ items.

Second term represents the case in which both items are defective. $\frac{4}{12}$ is probability of choosing one item from $4$ defective items and $\frac{3}{11}$ is probability of choosing another item from $3$ defective items.

**Approach 2:**

Total number of ways of choosing $2$ items out of $12$  $= \binom{12}{2} = 66$

Total number of ways of choosing $2$ non-defective items out of 8 $= \binom{8}{2} = 28$

Let $X$ denote number of defective items chosen.

Therefore,
$$
P(X = 0) = \frac{14}{33}
$$

Probability of choosing atleast one defective item is denoted by $P(X \ge 1)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
P(X \ge 1) &= 1 - P(X = 0) \\
&= 1 - \frac{14}{33} \\
&= \frac{19}{33}
\end{split}
$$

Why the first approach gives a wrong answer and why second approach works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first approach you have to count the first term twice, representing the fact that you can either pull a working item and then a defective one *or the other way around*. This gives
$$2×\frac4{12}×\frac8{11}+\frac4{12}×\frac3{11}=\frac{19}{33}$$

Comment: I thought the order in which cards are chosen is irrelevant in this case. Why does order matter if you can explain?

Comment: @jastor_007  By selecting one of $12$ items, then selecting one of the $11$ remaining items, you are taking order into account.

Comment: Also its not just a matter of order.  There are two ways you can get one defective item.  The first defective and the second not, and the second defective and the first not.  Both situations must be counted.